# Nested dictionary 'not in' is not working properly

Tags: python

I am trying to make a graph which for each item in a dictionary contains another dictionary of the neighbours and weights. I am using 'not in' to test to see if the current key is empty or not.

However, for some reason it is not working. I have tried testing outside and it works fine, but when I test my code it's not working and it returns 'True' every time meaning it is not identifying that there is a key.

X and Y are the nodes in my graph.
The if statement is always True even if it is in the dictionary

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

col=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'] 
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=col, error_bad_lines=False)
    
graph_dict = {}
    
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    
    if (df.iloc[i,0] not in graph_dict):
        graph_dict[df.iloc[i,0]] = {df.iloc[i,1] : df.iloc[i,3]}
    
    if (df.iloc[i,1] not in graph_dict):
        graph_dict[df.iloc[i,1]] = {df.iloc[i,0] : df.iloc[i,3]
```

Comment: I think it's `if not df.iloc[i,1] in graph_dict:`

Comment: @Dav_DidHu: That wouldn't change anything. Python has a `not in` operator that's equivalent to using `in` and then `not`-ing the result.

Comment: @Dav_DidHu unfortunately that didn't do anything

Comment: What's the type of `df.iloc[i,0]`?

Comment: I very much doubt that Python is doing the wrong thing.  Have you run your code in a debugger, stopped at those `if` statements, and looked to see what the key is you're looking for and what the contents of the dictionary actually is at that moment?  I don't know how many items we're talking about here, but you could alternately add some print statements to print the values of `df.iloc[i,0]` and `df.iloc[i,1]`, and the contents of the `graph_dict` dictionary.  If you did that, you could show us the result, or just a portion of it, to let us see what is going on with your code.

Comment: My guess would be `hash(df.iloc[i,0]) != hash(df.iloc[j,0])`, even if they "look" the same. You can check if that's true by printing the hashes. You can also try to convert the keys to string or int, depending on what type you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you all, It was the data that was causing the problem (well my lack of sleep). There was a whitespace character at the end of the column.